# React-Native component won't rerender on setState while original render is active

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

In my component constructor I load a list of "milestones" and the number of days since someone quit smoking. The milestones are hard-coded and load synchronously. The number of days is loaded from AsyncStorage. My component renders an AndroidProgressBar for each milestone where the progress for each progress bar is `this.state.days / milestone.duration`. During rendering the number of days is asynchronously returned and the state is updated with `setState({days})`. The changed state does not trigger a rerender, I assume because it is in the middle of the original render. This causes the progress bars for most of the milestones to be incorrect.

I've stepped through the debugger and I can see that the number of days is updated right before the last 2 milestones have been rendered, making only them correct.

Here's my component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Alert, AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Body, List, Title} from 'native-base';
import MilestoneItem from '../../components/MilestoneItem/MilestoneItem';

export default class MilestoneScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            milestones:[ ],
            days: 0
        };
        /* shape of milestones = [{title: str, duration: number}, ... ] */
        this.state.milestones = this.sortByDuration(props.storageManager.milestones());
        this.getDays();
    }

    async getDays() {
        let settings = await AsyncStorage.getItem("settings");
        settings = JSON.parse(settings);
        this.setState({days: settings.days});
    }

    // Sort the milestones by their duration.
    sortByDuration(array) {
        return array.sort(function(a, b) {
                var x = a.duration;
                var y = b.duration;
                return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        });
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Content>
                <List   dataArray={this.state.milestones}
                        renderRow={ (item) => {
                            let progress = item.duration > this.state.days ?  this.state.days / item.duration  : 1;
                            return <MilestoneItem milestone={item.title} progress={progress} />
                            }
                        }
                />
            </Content>
        </Container>
        );
    }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MilestoneScreen', () => MilestoneScreen);
```

Here are some debugger screens of the behavior. This photo shows the beginning of the render function.
[image]

This photo shows that once getDays() is called the state successfully is stored.
[image]

This photo shows that this.state.days has updated but the render function did not restart. Instead it just continued where it left off.

[image]

This photo shows the final result with every milestone being incorrect except for the final 2.

[image]

Comment: `..this.state.days has updated but the render function did not restart ...`, how `this.state.days` be updated?, your `getDays()` be deployed in constructor, which only fire once when first rendering

Comment: @Carr It's asynchronous so I call it in the constructor but it returns after, or during, render.

Answer (score 0):

The List component from React-Native triggers a rerender when the dataArray field is updated, not on anything in the the renderRow function. You must update the state of the dataArray field in order to trigger a rerender.

Tag for easy searching: List Component doesn't rerender.